# unable to publish vite react app to github

Tags: github, vite

I recently switched from react app to vit app, everything was fine, but until a certain point, I had to push the project to github so that my colleagues could see and evaluate the work I had done, it gives an error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

i I asked other developers, I also tried to get an answer to my question through the telegram groups, but everything that they recommended did not help, after that I, as a real developer, decided to google, I watched various videos, but all this did not help to solve my problem,

nothing is loading on the site and there is an ordinary white page